# WPF How Do I get the datagrid to add the next object dynamically to the next row instead of the current row?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In WPF I have a button which when clicked is supposed to add a new empty row to the datagrid for user input.  The problem is that it overwrites the current row with empty strings or 0 values rather than starting a new row.  How can I get it to start a new row?  I've tried to find a way to change the focus or commiting the editing on the current row and tried to find a way to increase the row count

```
<Window x:Class="Tourny2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tourny2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Structure Entry" Height="300" Width="850" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="16" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" ClipToBounds="True">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" CanUserAddRows="True" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="#FFCEE8E5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" FrozenColumnCount="1" ClipToBounds="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Levels" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding LevelName}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <TextBox x:Name="levelEntry"  Width="Auto"  Text="{Binding LevelName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Use Antes" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding UseAntes}" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="useAntes" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,5,6" Checked="useAntes_Checked" Unchecked="useAntes_Unchecked" IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="EnterAntes" Header="Antes" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Antes}" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="antesEntry" Width="Auto" IsEnabled="False" KeyDown="antesEntry_KeyDown" Text="{Binding Antes, TargetNullValue=' '}" Loaded="antesEntry_Loaded"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Small Blind" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding SmallBlind}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="SBEntry" Width="Auto" KeyDown="SBEntry_KeyDown" Text="{Binding SmallBlind}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Big Blind" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding BigBlind}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="BBEntry" Width="Auto" KeyDown="BBEntry_KeyDown" Text="{Binding BigBlind}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Level Time" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding LevelTime}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="levelTimeEntry" Width="Auto" KeyDown="levelTime_KeyDown"  Text="{Binding LevelTime}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="List Games" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding ListGames}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="listGames" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,5,6" Checked="listGames_Checked" Unchecked="listGames_Unchecked" IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Current Game" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding CurrentGame}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="gameEntry" Width="Auto" IsEnabled="False"   Text="{Binding CurrentGame, TargetNullValue=' '}" Loaded="gameEntry_Loaded"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="SaveStructure" Content="Save" FontFamily="Verdana" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="739,0,0,235" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="95" Click="saveStructure_Click" Height="27" ClipToBounds="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="LoadStructure" Content="Load" FontFamily="Verdana" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="739,0,0,206" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="95" Click="loadStructure_Click" Height="27" ClipToBounds="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="AddLevel" Content="Add Level" FontFamily="Verdana"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="739,0,0,177" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="95" Height="27" Click="addLevel_Click" ClipToBounds="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="AddBreak" Content="Add Break" FontFamily="Verdana"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="739,0,0,148" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="95" Height="27" Click="addBreak_Click" ClipToBounds="True"/>
</Grid>
```

```
namespace Tourny2
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private TextBox antesEntry;        
    private TextBox gameEntry;
    ObservableCollection<Level> levels = new ObservableCollection<Level>();
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        //levels.Add(new Level() { LevelName = "Level 1", UseAntes = false, SmallBlind = 25, BigBlind = 50, LevelTime = 20, ListGames = false } );
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = levels;
    }

    private void antesEntry_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        antesEntry = (sender as TextBox);            
    }

    private void gameEntry_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        gameEntry = (sender as TextBox);
    }

    private void useAntes_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox c = (sender as CheckBox);
        if (c.IsChecked == true)
        {            
            antesEntry.IsEnabled = true;               
        }
    }

    private void listGames_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox c = (sender as CheckBox);
        if (c.IsChecked == true)
        {
            gameEntry.IsEnabled = true;               
        }
    }

    private void useAntes_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox c = (sender as CheckBox);
        if (c.IsChecked == false)
        {
            antesEntry.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void listGames_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox c = (sender as CheckBox);
        if (c.IsChecked == false)
        {
            gameEntry.IsEnabled = false;

        }
    }

    private void antesEntry_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)          //allow only digits (keyboard and numbers pad)
    {                                                                       //tab and backspace to be entered in antes
        int key = (int)e.Key;
        e.Handled = !(key >= 34 && key <= 43 ||
        key >= 74 && key <= 83 || key == 2);
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }

    private void SBEntry_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)          //allow only digits (keyboard and numbers pad)
    {                                                                       //tab and backspace to be entered in SB
        int key = (int)e.Key;
        e.Handled = !(key >= 34 && key <= 43 ||
        key >= 74 && key <= 83 || key == 2);
        if(e.Key == Key.Tab|| e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }           
    }

    private void BBEntry_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)          //allow only digits (keyboard and numbers pad)
    {                                                                       //tab and backspace to be entered in BB
        int key = (int)e.Key;
        e.Handled = !(key >= 34 && key <= 43 ||
        key >= 74 && key <= 83 || key == 2);
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }

    private void levelTime_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)          //allow only digits (keyboard and numbers pad)                                                               
    {                                                                     //tab,and backspace to be entered in Level Time
        int key = (int)e.Key;
        e.Handled = !(key >= 34 && key <= 43 ||
        key >= 74 && key <= 83 || key == 2);
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab||e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }

    private void saveStructure_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid.SelectAllCells();
        dataGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.ExcludeHeader;
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dataGrid);
        dataGrid.UnselectAllCells();
        String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
        Clipboard.Clear();
        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("..\\"))
            {
                file.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addLevel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        AddNewRows(levels);            

    }

    private void AddNewRows(ObservableCollection<Level> levels)
    {
       // int rowCount = dataGrid.Items.Count;

        levels.Add(new Level());
    }

    private void addBreak_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewBreak(levels);
    }

    private void AddNewBreak(ObservableCollection<Level> levels)
    {
        levels.Add(new Level() { LevelName = "Break", UseAntes = false, SmallBlind = 0, BigBlind = 0});
    }

    private void loadStructure_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("..\\TestStructure.csv"))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                levels.Add(new Level(line));
            }
        }  
        // ... Use ItemsSource.            
       dataGrid.ItemsSource = levels;
       //dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    }
  }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is what you're entering in your row is not getting populated in your Collection `level`

So you can create a ViewModel and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` like

```
public ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

        private ObservableCollection<Level> mLevels;

        public ObservableCollection<Level> Levels
        {
            get
            {
                if (mLevels == null)
                {
                    mLevels = new ObservableCollection<Level>();
                }
                return mLevels;
            }
            set
            {
                mLevels = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Levels");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}
```

And in your Xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Levels,Mode=TwoWay}">
```